# Unable to connect Azure ubuntu VM through VS code

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04, azure-vm

Getting below issue while connecting Azure VM through VSCode but we are able to connect through Putty when we used .ppk file. Getting below error when we used both .ppk & .pem using ssh configin VSCode.
**Error**: Permission denied(Public key)

**Below are the ssh logs:**
`root@VMWDEPOCEUS001:/var/log# tail -30 auth.log  Oct 27 10:19:12 VMWDEPOCEUS001 sshd[3087]: Failed password for invalid user ssh user from 156.163.33.75 port 56425 ssh2 Oct 27 10:19:14 VMWDEPOCEUS001 sshd[3087]: Failed password for invalid user ssh user from 156.163.33.75 port 56425 ssh2 Oct 27 10:19:15 VMWDEPOCEUS001 sshd[3087]: Connection reset by invalid user ssh user 156.163.33.75 port 56425 [preauth] Oct 27 10:23:52 VMWDEPOCEUS001 sshd[3095]: Invalid user ssh user1 from 156.163.33.75 port 56590 Oct 27 10:23:57 VMWDEPOCEUS001 sshd[3095]: Failed none for invalid user ssh user1 from 156.163.33.75 port 56590 ssh2 Oct 27 10:24:00 VMWDEPOCEUS001 sshd[3095]: Failed password for invalid user ssh user1 from 156.163.33.75 port 56590 ssh2 Oct 27 10:24:04 VMWDEPOCEUS001 sshd[3095]: Failed password for invalid user ssh user1 from 156.163.33.75 port 56590 ssh2 Oct 27 10:24:05 VMWDEPOCEUS001 sshd[3095]: Connection reset by invalid user ssh user1 156.163.33.75 port 56590 [preauth] Oct 27 10:25:26 VMWDEPOCEUS001 sshd[3099]: Accepted password for user1 from 156.163.33.75 port 56649 ssh2 Oct 27 10:25:26 VMWDEPOCEUS001 sshd[3099]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user user1 by (uid=0) Oct 27 10:25:26 VMWDEPOCEUS001 systemd-logind[1238]: New session 6 of user user1. Oct 27 10:25:28 VMWDEPOCEUS001 sshd[3167]: Accepted password for user1 from 156.163.33.75 port 56651 ssh2 Oct 27 10:25:28 VMWDEPOCEUS001 sshd[3167]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user user1 by (uid=0) Oct 27 10:25:28 VMWDEPOCEUS001 systemd-logind[1238]: New session 7 of user user1. Oct 27 10:27:00 VMWDEPOCEUS001 sshd[3258]: Invalid user ssh user1 from 156.163.33.75 port 26689 Oct 27 10:27:14 VMWDEPOCEUS001 sshd[3258]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown Oct 27 10:27:14 VMWDEPOCEUS001 sshd[3258]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=156.163.33.75 Oct 27 10:27:16 VMWDEPOCEUS001 sshd[3258]: Failed password for invalid user ssh user1 from 156.163.33.75 port 26689 ssh2 Oct 27 10:27:30 VMWDEPOCEUS001 sshd[3258]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown Oct 27 10:27:33 VMWDEPOCEUS001 sshd[3258]: Failed password for invalid user ssh user1 from 156.163.33.75 port 26689 ssh2 Oct 27 10:27:47 VMWDEPOCEUS001 sshd[3258]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown Oct 27 10:27:49 VMWDEPOCEUS001 sshd[3258]: Failed password for invalid user ssh user1 from 156.163.33.75 port 26689 ssh2 Oct 27 10:27:49 VMWDEPOCEUS001 sshd[3258]: Connection reset by invalid user ssh user1 156.163.33.75 port 26689 [preauth] Oct 27 10:27:49 VMWDEPOCEUS001 sshd[3258]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=156.163.33.75 Oct 27 10:31:22 VMWDEPOCEUS001 sshd[3279]: Invalid user ssh user1 from 156.163.33.75 port 56826 Oct 27 10:31:34 VMWDEPOCEUS001 sshd[3279]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown Oct 27 10:31:34 VMWDEPOCEUS001 sshd[3279]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=156.163.33.75 Oct 27 10:31:35 VMWDEPOCEUS001 sshd[3279]: Failed password for invalid user ssh user1 from 156.163.33.75 port 56826 ssh2 Oct 27 10:32:09 VMWDEPOCEUS001 sshd[3279]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown Oct 27 10:32:10 VMWDEPOCEUS001 sshd[3279]: Failed password for invalid user ssh user1 from 156.163.33.75 port 56826 ssh2`

Expectation: Need to connect to Azure Ubuntu (18.04) VM using VSCode config file

Comment: Loads of reasons why you can't SSH to a VM. You would need to make sure `admin_user` & `pem` file perms are set correct. BTW, don't upload images in the questions, instead add the error message.
For more details, you need to logon to the machine via serial console & check `sshd` logs

Comment: Thanks for the reply @harshavmb, we have already checked the file permissions and ssh logs. pem file have same permissions as admin user.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment SSH is connected to Azure Ubuntu (18.04) VM using VSCode successfully.***

[image]

As per [Docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh-tutorial) Putty is not supported occurs an error. try to install OpenSSh client

Change your user as root:

```
sudo -s
```

Try to install `ssh` or if already install `update` it and enable your ssh and check whether your ***status is active*** like below

```
sudo apt-get install ssh    
sudo apt-get update
systemctl enable ssh.service 
systemctl status ssh.service
```

[image]

Generate a ***ssh key***. Try to avoid *ssh -i* please use `user@hostname` while configure ssh host like below.

[image]

Check whether u have provided config file ***host, user and hostname are correct.***

When I try to connect, I got the same error and ssh log like below.

[image]
[image]

***To resolve this issue:***

First try to change your password using `sudo passwd root` update the password and enable Password Authentication run `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config` it will open nano editor like below.

[image]

Once your nano editor change a filesystem permission of you scroll down place your cursor in `#` ***press insert insert*** type `PermitRootlogin yes` and `pubkeyauthentication yes` ***press escape &: x Enter***

[image]

Restart the SSH service by following this command:

```
sudo systemctl reload sshd
```

And try to connect with ssh `user@hostname` it's work.

If still you are facing issue, please check in root ssh install and update check status is active lie above and in nano editor check

```
PasswordAuthentication
ChallengeResponseAuthentication
GSSAPIAuthentication yes 
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
UsePAM yes
```

[image]

[image]

To know more in detail please ***refer*** this link:

[SSH Failed Permission Denied](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ssh-permission-denied-publickey)  by *phoenixnap*

[Connect over SSH with Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh-tutorial)

Comment: Thank you Imran, Issue has got resolved by uninstalling Remote-SSh and Python. I am able to connect now.Thanks.